# How do I stop my dropdown menu from jumping left to right?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap's responsive navbar, **in mobile devices** it displays a dropdown menu. This menu, be default, is aligned to the left. I changed this so that is displays to the right. I did achieve this. However, when I test on my iPhone (XR), the dropdown first shows on the left and quickly moves to the right, on its own. How can I stop this?

You can see a small video of what's happening [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfNVy.jpg).

```css
/* Navbar */
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    color:rgba(46, 46, 46, 1);
    border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand img {
  width: 75%;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(46, 46, 46, 1);
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #DA3D0D;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-custom-dropdown {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-custom-dropdown li a {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.navbar-custom-dropdown li a:hover,
.navbar-custom-dropdown li a:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #DA3D0D;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img src="images/logo-briones-monolithic.svg" alt="Briones Monolithic">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-custom-link" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">INICIO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">PROYECTOS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              GRUPO MONOLITHIC
            </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-custom-dropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">BRIONES MONOLITHIC</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">BE MONOLITHIC</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ELECTRIC MONOLITHIC</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">GRUPO MONOLITHIC</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACTO</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- /NAVBAR -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your demo code doesn't appear to show the menu on the right. How did you make your menu appear on the right? i.e. What did you add/change?

Comment: I changed the "ml-auto" to "mr-auto".

Comment: Your demo doesn't use `mr-auto`. Please provide a demo that represents your issue.